# How to use a ternary operator with multiple conditions inside of the super keyword?

Tags: java, ternary-operator

I am trying to turn the below code into one line of code using the super constructor and the ternary operator.
Have tried multiple things but nothing is working.

```
if (c == 0) {
    super(Piece.JMAN, x, y, Color.red);
} else if (c == 1) {
    super(Piece.JMAN, x, y, Color.green);
} else {
    super(Piece.JMAN, x, y, Color.yellow);
}
```

Comment: `super(Piece.JMAN, x, y, c == 0 ? Color.red : c == 1 ? Color.green : Color.yellow)`

Comment: @JacobG. why answer in a comment?

Comment: *"Have tried multiple things"* Like what? If you show what you've tried, we can better help you figure out what you did wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @jacobg wrote in the comments, you can do

```
super(Piece.JMAN, x, y, c == 0 ? Color.red : c == 1 ? Color.green : Color.yellow)
```

For purposes of readability, you might want to split it into two statements with added parentheses.

```
Color color = (c == 0 ? Color.red : (c == 1 ? Color.green : Color.yellow));
super(Piece.JMAN, x, y, color);
```

Comment: Why would you ever do this instead of using a switch statement?

Comment: A seasoned coder probably has no readability issues with a double conditional operator. The question also asked specifically for it.

Comment: I'm a beginner who is working on old programming assignments from universities. Is this a good idea to do?

Comment: No, you should make your code as readable as posible, unless you gain performance and it’s your objective.

Comment: @KingCold Since `super` constructor calls must be the first statement in the constructor you have to do the computations inline. However, if the expression is complicated consider extracting out the computations into a `private static` method (i.e. `super(computeColor(c))`).

Comment: @Powerlord You can't use a `switch` statement since a call to the `super` constructor must be the first statement in the constructor body. The OP's example `if`-`else` code shouldn't be compiling either.